# Recognizing a dollar sign in a tokenizer C

Tags: c, tokenize

I'm currently writing a simple program in C to parse an input string into words, separated by non-letter characters. It works for most inputs, however not for the dollar sign character.

Ex: if I input (./tokenizer hello1world), it would output "hello world", but if I have a dollar sign like "hello1world$again", the program would not output "again". If I include a specific check for it like "if (c == '$')", nothing happens.

What's so special about the dollar sign? Upon running it through GDB, I found out that the $ sign seems to mess with the strlen method, as well as seemingly terminate it early. An input like "f%s" gave me a length of 1 instead of 3.

Edit: It would seem that characters like the dollar sign and the exclamation mark are interpreted as commands in the terminal, so how do I account for those? For example, an input like "sup!hello" gives me an error saying that "!hello" is not a command.

```
void parse_input(char *input) {
    int length = strlen(input);
    int non_letter_index = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = input[i];
        /*checks if it's not a letter*/
        if (c == '$' || !isalpha(c)) {
            char *segment;
            if (non_letter_index == 0) {
                segment = get_substring(input, 0, i);
            }
            else {
                if (non_letter_index + 1 != length) {
                    segment = get_substring(input, non_letter_index + 1, i);
                }
            }
            non_letter_index = i;
            if (strlen(segment) > 0) {
                insert_word(segment);
            }
        }

    }
    /*adds the last string after the last non-letter character*/
    if (non_letter_index != length - 1) {
        char *last_word;
        int starting_index = non_letter_index;
        if (non_letter_index != 0) {
            starting_index++;
        }
        last_word = get_substring(input, starting_index, length);
        if (strlen(last_word) > 0) {
            insert_word(last_word);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Nothing's special about it. Have you debugged it line by line to see what happens?

Comment: Write a simple test program that reads characters, and outputs their decimal equivalents. Here are the decimal values for the [printable ascii characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). The dollar sign is 36. If the test program prints 36 when you enter a dollar sign, then there's nothing special about the dollar sign. If it doesn't print 36, then let us know what it does print.

Comment: I just ran it through gdb, and it would seem that strlen seems to cut the length short; an input like "f$s" yields a length of 1 when it's supposed to be 3.

Testing the ascii value gives me 36.

Comment: some *nix shells like bash treat $ as a special character, so please ensure that it is not a command line related problem and the input actually reaches your main `argv` parameter (if that's the source of your input).

Comment: Have a look at [How can I echo dollar signs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162476/how-can-i-echo-dollar-signs), it may help you for terminal related problems

Comment: @Darius Hint... ***single-quote*** your command line to prevent the shell variable expansion from taking place.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ooh that did the trick! Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things that work `:)`